# Galaxy S7 Nougat--When charging, screening keeps coming on

Tags: samsung, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s7

Recently upgraded to Nougat on my Samsung Galaxy S7.  Only issue is that when i am charging , the screen keeps turning on to show it is charging, then goes dark, then turns on again.  The only way to mitigate, is to turn on the screensaver when charging.  any thoughts?

Comment: Try checking up your battery  and screen settings.... some random option might've been enabled, else its not supposed to be.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking "Stay awake" in developer options which makes the screen never sleep while charging.